# How to recognize if the device is processing tasks too slow

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically detect when the device is struggling to keep up with all the tasks, more specifically with UI tasks such as animations and updating UI elements.

The point of it would be to programmatically stop certain animations if the device can't handle them all.